# Removing onchange event vis the dom

Tags: javascript, events, handler

I have the following html

```
<td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="left" rowspan="4">
<div id="win0divCLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$">
<input type="text"
    onchange="addchg_win0(this);oChange_win0=this;"
    maxlength="8"
    style="width:60px; "
    class="PSEDITBOX"
    value=""
    tabindex="31"
    id="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$"
    name="CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$" />
</div></td>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to either delete the onchange from the element, or to set it to null..

Articles I've seen indicate that using the removeEventlistener should work. I've tried::

```
document.getElementById(\"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$\").removeEventListener('onchange',addchg_win0(this);oChange_win0=this;, false)
```

as well as

```
document.getElementById(\"CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$\").onchange=null;
```

with no luck.

Any pointers/thoughts on this??

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$").attributes.onchange=null;`, And if that gives some error, try using `function(){}` instead of `null`.

Comment: No working solution yet

Answer (score 1):

give a try to `document.getElementById("CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$").removeAttribute("onchange");`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.getElementById("CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$69$").onchange="";
```