# Stop onChange method from calling for every key press

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to stop onChange method from being called on every key press (call it only once by first key press) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing onchange event vis the dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147355/removing-onchange-event-vis-the-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable to control it.

```
var pressed = false;
```

Then, change the variable to `true` after first key press. Perform the actions only if the variable is `false`.

```
if (pressed == false) { /* do action here */ }
```